# CSS background-size property above `100%` means?

Tags: html, css

I'm doing gradient animation and I apply

`background-size: 100% 100%;` but it's not working.

then I tried `background-size: 600% 600%;` now its working fine.

In pixel and up to 100% I understood. but above 100% I'm not getting
Can anyone explain to me what is this means : `600% 600%?` how it is calculating?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you give height and width in percentage

It Stretches the image in the corresponding dimension to the specified percentage of the background positioning area. The background positioning area is determined by the value of background-origin (by default, the padding box). However, if the background's background-attachment value is fixed, the positioning area is instead the entire viewport. Negative values are not allowed.

These are some of the good articles  which give you explanation in brief

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#the-background-size

this one for gradients

https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-3/#gradients